# PYTHON: POST xml file

Tags: python, xml

my xmlFile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Task>
    <Date>2020-06-24</Date>
    <Time>10:40</Time>
    <Main>
        <Type>Car</Type>
        <Task1>Something</Task1>
        <Task2>Something</Task2>
        <Task3>Something</Task3>
        <Task4>Something</Task4>
        <Task5>RESULT</Task5>
        <Task6>1</Task6>
        <Task7>103</Task7>
        <Bill>
            <Type>$</Type>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
        </Bill>
        <Handball>false</Handball>
        <Football>false</Football>
        <Book>false</Book>
    </Main>
</Task>
```

my code.py

```
xmlFile = 'test.xml'
API_URL = XXX

    with open(xmlFile) as xml:
       r= requests.post(API_URL, data=xmlFile)
    print(r.text)
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Status>
    <Code>ERROR_FORMAT_INVALID</Code>
    <Description>The supplied data could not be imported in the stated input format.</Description>
  </Status>
  <Status>
    <Code>ERROR</Code>
    <Description>The supplied data could not be imported in the stated input format - [XML2Array] Error parsing the XML string.</Description>
  </Status>
</Response>
```

What i want is:

I have 200 XML files which i want to post (file by file) and receive Data. In this case specifi the Type $ and Amount '100'. I know that i would get different results thats why i want to save the results from all 200 xml files to one txt file.

As shown below i receive this error. How can i fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to share the API docs.

Comment: You said "you can post it from HTML". This means there is a HTML form? In this case you need to post a "multipart" request, quite possibly with a bunch of form fields in the first part and the XML file in the second part. `requests` can do this, there are plenty of examples. But without seeing the HTML form (or better yet, the request it creates) it's gonna be impossible to tell you what to do in `requests` to replicate.

Comment: yes i also tried it but it doesn't work :(

Comment: *"it doesn't work :("* does not give us enough info to help you.

Comment: @Tomalak found the error: 
filesXML = {'file': open('some.xml', 'rb')}
Now it works

Comment: Nice, good to hear you found the solution on your own! You could write *that* as an answer and tick it as accepted. This will also mark the thread as solved.